# How do I fail a particular test step in SoapUI using groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

So i have a test step lets call it "Step1" after this executes, i should have some data in DB (for this i have a dataSource step added).
I want to write a groovy script which will fail "Step1" if no data is found in "dataSource" step.

Comment: Why can't you just fail the DataSource test?

Answer (score 0):

You can add some assertions in the datasource step that make the step fail.

[image]